# Keep locale on Spring Security session timeout

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3.0.2 and I have this config

```
    <security:form-login
        login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/login"
         authentication-failure-handler-ref="authErrorHandler" authentication-success-handler-ref="authCorrectHandler" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" invalidate-session="false" />
    <security:remember-me />
    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login/sessionExpired" >
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </security:session-management>
```

When I login with a certain locale, all went well but when expiring session, Spring Security clear session and create new anonymous session with locale by default (and go to the login page as expected). The result is the user locale was LOST.

How can I keep the user locale when expiring session in Spring Security 3.0.2?

I'm using localeChangeInterceptor to set the locale, like this:

```
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
```

and SessionLocaleResolver as locale resolver:

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
</bean>
```

---

### **EDIT - SOLVED FOR MY NEEDS**

I've solved this finally setting a **cookie** in my own **LocaleChangeInterceptor** which extends from **HandlerInterceptorAdapter**, writing this in **preHandle** method:

```
     LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
     if (localeResolver == null) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("No LocaleResolver found.");
     }
     Cookie mylang = new Cookie("mylang", locale.getLanguage() + "_" + locale.getCountry());
     mylang.setMaxAge(86400); 
     response.addCookie(mylang);

     localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, locale);
```

and then in the **/sessionExpired** controller point, I'm getting the cookie value:

```
public String sessionExpired(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, 
        @CookieValue(value = "mylang", defaultValue = "es_ES") String myLang) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("mylang", myLang);
    LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myLang, "_");

    String language = "";
    String country = "";

    try {
        language = (String) st.nextElement();
        country = (String) st.nextElement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error locale");
    }

    Locale locale = new Locale(language, country); 
    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, locale);
    return "sessionExpired";
```

No need to use database as temporal storage in this case.

Comment: Can you post how you are setting locale?

Comment: updated post showing how I'm setting locale

Comment: Logically it does not look like you can use the session to keep track of the locale. The locale is set using a request param `language` which will be cleared with the session. When a new session is created the locale is defaulted to `es` as given by your `localeResolver`. One way I could think is to store user preferences in a DB and retrieve from there on subsequent log-ins.

Comment: Correct, that's what I'm thinking. But I was hoping Spring Security maybe had any mechanism to keep and not destroy the locale.

Comment: You are using the `SessionLocaleResolver` which, obviously stores it in the session. No session no stored locale. If you are ok with cookies use the `CookieLocaleResolver` which persists the choice in a cookie. Else implement your own `LocaleResolver` which stores/retrieves from database.

Answer (score 2):

Logically it does not look like you can use the session to keep track of the locale. The locale is set using a request param `language` which will be cleared with the session. When a new session is created the locale is defaulted to `es` as given by your `localeResolver`. One way I could think is to store user preferences in a DB and retrieve from there on subsequent log-ins

Also as suggested by @M. Deinum:

If you are ok with cookies use the `CookieLocaleResolver` which persists the choice in a cookie. Else implement your own `LocaleResolver` which stores/retrieves from database.

Comment: I don't know why but CookieLocaleResolver itself doesn't works for me at login time, keep the previous stored locale instead current one. Anyway, session timeout work as expected and keep the locale. Let me check the problem at login time.

Comment: I've updated the question with a solution working for me. Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this old question and just thought of sharing how I got away with my predicament using a `Filter` (would've preferred an `Interceptor` but for some reason it annoyingly ain't working for me as of this writing).

```java
public class SessionTimeoutFilter implements Filter {

    private String contextPath;

    private String language;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) {
        contextPath = config.getInitParameter("context.path");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        String path = request.getRequestURI();

        if (path.equals(contextPath)) { //the index page
            request.getSession(true);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

            if (session != null) {
                language = (String) session.getAttribute("lang");
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect(contextPath + "?timeout=true&lang=" + language);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And on top of a `LocaleChangeInterceptor`, I had parameters in my `Controller`.

```java
@GetMapping("/")
public String home(@RequestParam(value = "timeout", required = false) Boolean timeout,
                   @RequestParam(value = "lang", required = false) String language,
                   HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    if (Strings.isNotBlank(language)) {
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(new Locale(language));
    } else {
        language = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage();
    }

    if (BooleanUtils.isTrue(timeout)) {
        String message = messageService.getMessage("error.timeout", null);
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
    }

    request.getSession().setAttribute("lang", language);
    return "index";
}
```